# What is the Lua equivalent to python's "in" statement?

Tags: python, lua

Does Lua have any statement equivalent to the "in" statement of python?

Example:

```
if "word" in variable:
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656199/search-for-an-item-in-a-lua-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search for an item in a Lua list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656199/search-for-an-item-in-a-lua-list)

Comment: What is `variable`? Is it a string? A table?

Comment: Python's `in` works differently for strings, lists, and dicts. Do you need code examples for all 3?

Answer (score 2):

Lua has no equivalent of Python's `in` operator, but if you know what container type you want to emulate, it's easy to write a function for it.

### `str`

The `true` argument ensures that the substring is treated literally and not as a pattern. See [`string.find`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.find) for details.

```
local function inString(s, substring)
  return s:find(substring, 1, true)
end
```

### `list`

```
local function inArray(array, x)
  for _, v in ipairs(array) do
    if v == x then
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end
```

### `dict`

```
local function inKeys(t, k)
  return t[k] ~= nil
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use find

```
string.find('banana', 'an')
```

see https://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html